# Alternative to using JS .load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an alternative to using .load to refresh the contents of a Div? Bascially I'm using .load below to reload the div after an object has been removed. But at the moment this is'nt working correctly.

.load is returning a div without results, even though there should be objects within it. When I refresh the page manually the correct results show.

Therefore, Could I just remove the object from view the user has clicked on instead?

```
     /////////////////////SECTION 1 - This code block returns the current users friends to the page. THIS IS NOT USED IN THE FILTER//////
    $('#containerFriends').empty();
    $('#friendsProfile').hide();
    $('#container').empty();
    $('#containerFriendsConnected').empty();


    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

    var queryOne = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
    queryOne.equalTo("toUser", currentUser);


    var queryTwo = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
    queryTwo.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);

    var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(queryOne, queryTwo);
    mainQuery.include('toUser');
    mainQuery.include('fromUser');
    mainQuery.equalTo("status", "Connected");


    mainQuery.find({
        success: function(results) {
            var friends = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                friends.push({
                    imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                    username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                    userId: results[i].get('toUser').id,
                    status: results[i].get('status'),



                    // Saves the object so that it can be used below to change the status//
                    fetchedObject: results[i]


                });


            }
            var select = document.getElementById("FriendsConnected");
            $.each(friends, function(i, v) {
                var opt = v.username;
                var el = document.createElement("option");
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.value = opt;
                select.appendChild(el);
            })


            $('#containerFriends').empty();
            $('#containerFriendsConnected').empty();

            _.each(friends, function(item) {
                var wrapper = $('<div class="portfolio-item-thumb one-third"></div>');
                wrapper.append('<img class="responsive-image friendImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />' + '<br>');
                wrapper.append('<div class="tag">' + item.username + '</div>');
                wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="btn btn-danger mrs decline">' + 'Unfriend' + '</div>');

                $('#containerFriends').append(wrapper);



                //The following lets the user accept or decline a friend request by changing the status the status from Pending to Declined/////
                wrapper.children('.decline').click(function() {
                    $(".decline").click(function() {
                        item.fetchedObject.set("status", "Rejected");

                        $( "#containerFriends" ).load("friends.html #containerFriends" );

                        item.fetchedObject.save(null, {
                            success: function(results) {
                                console.log("REJECTED");

                            },
                            error: function(contact, error) {
                                // The save failed.
                                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                            }
                        });


                    });


                });

            });

        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The question is, do you want a solution using jquery or a solution not using jquery?

Comment: what isn't working? Need to define your problem better and why you want to replace `load()`

Comment: off topic: since you've been using jquery `document.getElementById("FriendsConnected");` can be short written as `$("#FriendsConnected");`

Comment: @charlietfl I've added further detail and more of the code, thank you

Comment: you probably just want something like `wrapper.remove()` instead